# How to listen to the specific event using Socket.IO from different files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I want to listen to the specific event using Socket.IO in different files.

I tried to use "io.on('event')" - but that doesn't work

Here is part of my code:
index.js

```
global.io = require('socket.io')(3000)

global.io.on('connection', client => {

// Some events

})
```

views/page.js:

```
global.io.to(freeServer.socketId).emit('example', {
    message
})

// Here I want to listen to the response, like:
global.io.on('response', myFunction)
```

Comment: Did you go through the official documentation? https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ What I have understood from your question is you are emitting event from the server and you want to listen to specific even from different places, right?

Comment: @ShocKwav3_, yes